# How to correctly wait for the elements to get their correct width before accessing it in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make buttons the same width but I'm having problems actually waiting for Angular 2 to finish all the rendering and stuff before accessing the width of the buttons.

I tried using `DoCheck` which "works", by "works" I mean that it does pick up the correct width value, but only the second time it runs.

Since `NgDoCheck` runs twice for some reason, as soon as I add the `button.style.width = widest + 'px';` statement, the buttons will all get a width of `115px`, so the second time `ngDoCheck` runs, it will go over all the buttons again, but this time all the buttons will be set to `115px`, so `widest` can never become the correct value of `159px` since we set the value the first time `ngDoCheck` ran.

What would be the correct way to go about this issue? Using `DoCheck` just seems wrong since it runs twice, and I'm not really checking input values which is `DoCheck`'s use case when reading the docs.

```
export class ButtonGroupComponent implements DoCheck {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngDoCheck() {

    if (this.equalWidth) {

      let buttons = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('button');
      let widest = 0;

      for (var button of buttons) {

        if (button.getBoundingClientRect().width > widest) {
          widest = button.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }
      }

      for (var button of buttons) {
        button.style.width = widest + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess plunker code would help better. Becasue for me its kinda debug and test problem.

Comment: @micronyks I actually found out that using `AfterViewInit` solved the problem, missed it the first time I went through the docs.

Comment: If all your buttons are in the same element, I recommend using css `flexbox`. [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PtfSTV8Zf7x16kiwrMyt?p=preview)

Comment: @Abdulrahman Although that would suffice as a correct method, it's not the best in my scenario as you can choose whether the buttons should have the same width or not. I could add the flexbox as a class but I rather have small css files in my case. I'd give it an upvote if posted as an answer but since it's not a direct solution to the question I would not mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Your answer is the correct answer. I just thought to mention the flexbox because it's always better to avoid javascript if you can get the same result without it.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Yeah that is true. I will take it under consideration, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `AfterViewInit` seems to do the trick, it only execute once resulting in the correct behavior and correct values. It's as simple as swapping `DoCheck` and `ngDoCheck` for `AfterViewInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
export class ButtonGroupComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    if (this.equalWidth) {

      let buttons = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('button');
      let widest = 0;

      for (var button of buttons) {

        if (button.getBoundingClientRect().width > widest) {
          widest = button.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }
      }

      for (var button of buttons) {
        button.style.width = widest + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else doing DOM manipulation.

Comment: Its because DOM becomes ready for the manipulation with ngAfterViewInit. So if you think to manipulate DOM, this could be a better hook to go ahead (my thinking)